# TypeScript: Infer type from discriminated union to create a map?

Tags: typescript

```
enum ShapeType { Circle, Square }

interface Circle {
    kind: ShapeType.Circle,
    radius: number
}

interface Square {
    kind: ShapeType.Square,
    sideLength: number
}

type Shape = Circle | Square

type WhatShape<T extends ShapeType>   // <-- can we do without WhatShape?
    = T extends ShapeType.Circle ? Circle
    : T extends ShapeType.Square ? Square
    : never;

type ShapeMap = {
    [K in ShapeType]: (s: WhatShape<K>) => void
}


const handlers: ShapeMap = {
    [ShapeType.Circle]: (c: Circle) => {
        console.log(c.radius)
    },
    [ShapeType.Square]: s/*inferred!*/ => {
        console.log(s.sideLength)
    },
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygFgQwA7ACoE8VQN5QMICWATgMYA2wANLAI5gJHBQC+AUKwSAC7BEBmCEk0KkKOVlElQA1pwAmALliIUGFADoR5KhKlEEcgmADOS8BABGvVmw7deAobXqNxUmfKXxkaTMHUwdAw67sYEcsAAMqAA5lxwZpBWRDbsXH7KPlAAvPjE2lAAPs7BaRkA6ohc3igAPKhQwAAePCByxpmqfgB8upK5Dc2t7Z2+GlpiAPx5osB9UEqDLaAjNWP+gS5M05ul7mbAAG68ANxlWGsAssg5blIA2gDSUJyjasAAukoAFKZQlQhqipgLVHt0AJQ5bpQQ4Ae3CqXYJFhIGMXCgiDaFCIfyuN1y2Hm9zW700+QoXyg3xISgmwEh2WhhPc7mRqNhFHUZFhMWp6n0hhM4PmzEoRJJfgCQUYlI6jLuLKgbOMHP83N5xnUYQi0RAcTgwvcosRQA)

This works, but it's a little annoying to have to maintain `WhatShape` to map the enum back to the shape kind.

Is there any way that TS can infer the argument type for our `ShapeMap` from the `kind`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to find the member(s) of a union `T` assignable to a type `U`.  In your case, `T` would be the [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type `Shape`, and `U` would be an object type whose `kind` property is the particular member(s) of `ShapeType` you are trying to map.  So `WhatShape<T>` could be defined as:

```
type WhatShape<T extends ShapeType> = Extract<Shape, { kind: T }>
```

And it will behave the same as your existing version without needing to be maintained separately from `Shape`:

```
type ShapeMap = {
    [K in ShapeType]: (s: WhatShape<K>) => void
}
/* type ShapeMap = {
    0: (s: Circle) => void;
    1: (s: Square) => void;
} // same as before */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: `Extract`! That's awesome. Thank you, exactly what I was looking for